# Customize the Mylyn Context UI?

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

In Mylyn, if you activate a task and use the context UI feature, the package explorer shows the classes belonging to this tasks context AND the method you are within.

Is it possible to customize/configure the Mylyn Context UI to:

- show only the class name
- NOT go deeper into the class
- and also show the methods?

For me it's not convenient if the filtered package explorer view contains also the methods, and it would be enough if the context visible in the package explorer showed the packages and class names only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the package explorer you can click on the upper-right down-arrow and select 'Filters...' and filter out java members, fields, import declarations, etc.  Afterwards, only packages and classes should show up.

This will work on Helios, but I know on some older version of Eclipse, Mylyn wouldn't let me change the filter while I was 'Focused' on a task.  However, I could get it to work by changing the filter before putting any task in focus.

Comment: Thanks a lot, filtering 'Java member' was exactly what I'm looking for. I've using this filter before, but never together with Mylyn. I using Helios too and -as you mentioned- one have to set the filter before you activate any task ! Thank you !